# Why can I not right-align an element with display: block and width: X?

Tags: css, layout, text-alignment

Total n00b question here (at least to the CSS elite):

Why is it that an element with both `display: block;` and a value for `width` does not seem to fall in line with the `text-align` property of its parent? That is, it always seems to insist on keeping to the left.

[Here is a jsFiddle illustrating the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Twf/)

Obviously, this must be consistent with the CSS spec (I mean, if Chrome, Firefox and Opera all agree on it, I have very little doubt); I just don't really get it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The text is aligned right inside a 150px box. That is correct. A block element will not align to text-align in the parent.

To fix this you need to use either `display: inline-block` or `float: right` on the .width div.

edit: with float, add `clear: right` to avoid it being on the same line as the previous div

Answer (score 1):

`<span>` is an element with `display: inline`. Elements with `display: inline` following the text alignment. Elements with `display: block` does not follow the alignment of text are aligned OWNED by the float.

When you just change the width of the element remains inline, following the alignment of text, but when you change your display to block and change its width, its content assumes the alignment of text, but the element does not. I tried to illustrate this with some color in your code ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Twf/3/

Answer (score 1):

alternative way

```
<div style="text-align:right; margin:0px auto 0px auto;">
<p> Hello </p>
</div>
  <div style="">
<p> Hello </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your class is block width not width. Rename the class block_width and then in your css make the last one .block_width rather than the .width you have and it works